# Does the JIT compiler produce binary code ( 0s and 1s )?

Tags: .net-framework

Does the Just in Time Compiler of the .net framework produce assembly language or binary code? In other words, does the output of the JIT compiler have to pass through an assembler before it targets the processor. If the JIT produces assembly language, is there a way to see this assembly language output?

Comment: "Does the JIT compiler produce 0s and 1s?" I sure hope this title is supposed to be a joke...can you please make it more meaningful?

Comment: I think the OP means 010101 (binary code) ...

Comment: It produces assembly code that the CPU can understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compile a .NET program, MSIL (might be called CIL now) is generated.  MSIL is a "byte-code" - something like a slightly higher level assembly language that isn't designed to run on any real CPU.

This must be "just-in-time" compiled (JITted) to native code.  Your CPU only understands native code.  Native code is architecture-specific, i.e. ARM native code won't work on x86, and vice versa.

Object code is what an assembler or compiler outputs before it is put through a process called linking.  Grossly simplifying, linking enables the code to use subroutines, functions, and APIs in other libraries (like .dlls), frameworks (like COM, etc.) and the operating system itself - after linking, you have an executable you can use.  Object code is architecture specific as well.

The JIT compiler doesn't invoke a separate program to create assembly (not on Windows, anyway) - there is no intermediate human-readable text "assembly language" file created.  I'm sure it just directly emits the binary instructions itself.  You can reverse engineer and disassemble it as you would any other .exe.  This is very involved and usually a lot of work.

All code, whether text, source, native, machine, assembly, object, etc., is a stream of binary data.  It ends up as such in the CPU's memory when it is loaded.  When stored in a file, it's usually wrapped in an executable format (Portable Executable, or PE on Windows) that also contains additional data, placed elsewhere in RAM when loaded upon an execute request from the OS, such as static data referenced by the program (constant integers and strings, resources like icons, etc.), the DLL's it uses, and other stuff.  References for the PE format are readily available.

Answer (score 1):

JIT Compiler of the .NET frameworks "reads" byte-code and produces pure binary machine code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ht8ecch6(v=vs.71).aspx

> Before you can run Microsoft intermediate language (MSIL), it must be
>   **converted by a .NET Framework just-in-time (JIT) compiler to native
>   code**, which is CPU-specific code that runs on the same computer
>   architecture as the JIT compiler. Because the common language runtime
>   supplies a JIT compiler for each supported CPU architecture,
>   developers can write a set of MSIL that can be JIT-compiled and run on
>   computers with different architectures.

Comment: Are Native Code, Machine Code and Object Code, all essentially binary code (0s and 1s)?

Comment: Yes there are binary (0s and 1s).

Comment: Um... just like everything else.

Comment: @Foo *Every instruction or data* the CPU works with is essentially binary code 0s and 1s. Native code and machine code are the same and directly executable by the CPU. In contrast an intermediate language with byte code (as used by Java) is not directly executable by the CPU and requires an interpreter.